# Set output to 1 if 5 or more days have passed since the last eligible entry

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table:

```
ID  DATE_CREATION
-----------------
S1     01/01/2022
S2     04/01/2022
S3     07/01/2022
S4     09/01/2022
S5     10/01/2022
```

I would like to implement this logic: the oldest line (S1) will have output 1. For the subsequent lines, if 5 or
more days have passed from the previous entry with an output = 1, mark that output as 1 and continue evaluating.

The expected output would look something like this (4th column included for explanation purposes).

```
ID  DATE_CREATION   OUTPUT  OUTPUT_EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------
S1     01/01/2022        1  It is the first entry
S2     04/01/2022        0  5 days have not passed since the last eligible entry (S1)
S3     07/01/2022        1  5 days have passed since the last eligible entry (S1)
S4     09/01/2022        0  5 days have not passed since the last eligible entry (S3) 
S5     10/01/2022        0  5 days have not passed since the last eligible entry (S3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       date_creation,
       CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS output
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  ORDER BY DATE_CREATION
  MEASURES
    COUNT(*) AS rn
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (five_days+)
  DEFINE
    five_days AS date_creation < FIRST(date_creation) + INTERVAL '5' DAY
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, DATE_CREATION) AS
SELECT 'S1', DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'S2', DATE '2022-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'S3', DATE '2022-01-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'S4', DATE '2022-01-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'S5', DATE '2022-01-10' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | DATE_CREATION | OUTPUT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | S1 | 01-JAN-22 | 1 |
> | S2 | 04-JAN-22 | 0 |
> | S3 | 07-JAN-22 | 1 |
> | S4 | 09-JAN-22 | 0 |
> | S5 | 10-JAN-22 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5eb7c838a9dce392d257d427345ecf13)*

Comment: Thanks! Is count over partition (to allow partitioning by ids) supported by MATCH_RECOGNIZE? I did not include it in my original question because I thought it would be trivial afterwards, but it is turning out not so trivial.

Comment: @JaviTorre Not entirely sure what you mean but it could be something like either of these two options [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=01dcd025736357901fcec9074969a371).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Just one question: what does num_days mean?

Comment: It is just an alias given to the column. It could have been called anything but I decided that it was probably counting the number of days in the match so called is `num_days` as short for "number of days".

Comment: Counting the number of days in the match: apologies, did not understand this bit: do you mean the number of times the rn is 1?

Comment: No, counting the number of rows between the start of the current match and the start of the next match.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer and yet better explanation! Accepted answer!

Comment: apologies, one additional question. Would it be possible to count only those rows that meet a certain condition?

Comment: Probably but you haven't said what it is.

Comment: Imagine there was a third column in the input data that had number values and I would like to only run the condition for the positive ones. @MT0

Comment: You mean like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=69f5de67229a7dc8007b1e6f5ff59c3c)?

Comment: This one is removing the rows where value < 0. I would need to show them but not using them for the output count.

Comment: I have tried https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b2ce58a435a0e6d60b4cc99d59f4ce77 but it is also removing negative rows.

Comment: @JaviTorre Maybe [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=94546acb95a88f8ffaa896b9d5076370). If that isn't what you want then you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide a [MRE] with sample data and expected output rather than continuing this in comments.